# How can I calculate the number of weeks since a given date in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, date, date-arithmetic

### Objective

I am trying to calculate the *distance in **weeks*** since a given date without jumping through hoops. I'd prefer to do it in plain Ruby, but ActiveSupport is certainly an acceptable alternative.

### My Code

I wrote the following, which seems to work but looks like the long way around to me.

```
require 'date'

DAYS_IN_WEEK = 7.0 

def weeks_since date_string
  date  = Date.parse date_string
  days  = Date.today - date
  weeks = days / DAYS_IN_WEEK
  weeks.round 2
end

weeks_since '2015-06-15'
#=> 32.57
```

ActiveSupport's [#weeks_since](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#extensions-to-date) takes a number of weeks as its argument, so it doesn't fit this use case. Ruby's [Date class](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html) doesn't seem to have anything relevant, either.

### Alternatives?

Is there a better built-in solution or well-known algorithm for calculating the number of weeks separating a pair of dates? I'm not trying to code-golf this, as readability trumps brevity, but simply to learn whether Ruby natively supports the type of date arithmetic I've coded by hand.

Comment: Weeks do not start on the same day across the world. Which definition are you taking? Or, by week, do you actually mean days/7? For example based on Monday-starting week, Jan 30, 2016 and Jan 31, 2016 belong to the same week, but based on Sunday-starting week, they belong to different weeks.

Comment: Using times it would be `(t2 - t1) /  604800`. Which is `(60 * 60 * 24 * 7)` = 1 week in seconds. otherwise your solution will also do a similar thing.

Comment: @sawa I think he is defining week in a much purer sense of 7 contiguous days.

Comment: @engineersmnky You're correct. I'm defining weeks as blocks of 7 contiguous days, rather than "work weeks" or "calendar weeks."

Comment: You could say, "distance in meters" or "time in weeks", but not "distance in weeks". :-)

Comment: if you just mean 7-day increments, as the code you've got does, I don't see anything wrong with the code you've got or any reason to improve it.

Answer (score 16):

```
require 'date'

str = '2015-06-15'

Date.parse(str).step(Date.today, 7).count                  # => 33
Date.parse(str).upto(Date.today).count.fdiv(7).round(2)    # => 32.71
```

Comment: Okay, I see [Date#step](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-step) defined, but even after reading the docs, I'm not sure why your example works.

Comment: `Date#step` accepts an other `Date` object, and a number. It will return an `Enumerator` object, consist of the days difference between those two dates. `Date#upto(some_date)` is equivalent as `Date#step(some_date, 1)`.

Comment: It is helpful to point out that the second argument pertains to the _number of days per step_. This is not well documented [as of Ruby 2.4.1](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-step).

Comment: To be more precise, the first one should be `Date.parse(str).step(Date.today, 7).count - 1` so that `(Date.current - 7.days).step(Date.current, 7).count - 1 == 1`

Answer (score 8):

Might be easier to convert the dates to time and then divide the time difference by a week. You can `round` it however you want or `ceil`.

```
def weeks_since(date_string)
  time_in_past = Date.parse(date_string).to_time
  now = Time.now
  time_difference = now - time_in_past
  (time_difference / 1.week).round(2)
end
```

Answer (score 7):

### in_weeks (Rails 6.1+)

Rails 6.1 introduces new [ActiveSupport::Duration](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html) conversion methods like [in_seconds](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html#method-i-in_seconds), [in_minutes](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html#method-i-in_minutes), [in_hours](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html#method-i-in_hours), [in_days](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html#method-i-in_days), [in_weeks](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html#method-i-in_weeks), [in_months](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html#method-i-in_months), and [in_years](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html#method-i-in_years).

As a result, now, your problem can be solved as:

```rb
date_1 = Time.parse('2020-10-18 00:00:00 UTC')
date_2 = Time.parse('2020-08-13 03:35:38 UTC') 

(date_2 - date_1).seconds.in_weeks.to_i.abs
# => 9
```

Here is [a link to the corresponding PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/38699).